# Knockout foreach - set attr

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello I'm using knockout foreach to generate my layout. I have problems with settings attributes in proper way. Here is my code:

```
   <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: points">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="oferty" data-bind="event: { mouseenter: $parent.mouseEnter, mouseout: $parent.mouseOut}">
            <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
            <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to populate in some way attribute data-name with my points -> name data. To get something like here:

```
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="Test1" id="oferty">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="Test2" id="oferty">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
```

I tried:

```
addAttributes: {'data-name': name}
```

and

```
attr: {'data-name': name}
```

But none of them works.
Can someone suggest my simple solution of my problem?

**Update1 Answer for the nemesv**
No errors in the console.

```
    var poszukiwane = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
```

Above code always returns undefined...

**Update2: adding Jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nnsBQ/3/

But don't know how to include more than 1 js framework there so will throw error in one line

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? The following should work: `<div class="col-md-4" id="oferty" data-bind="event: { mouseenter: $parent.mouseEnter, mouseout: $parent.mouseOut}, attr: { 'data-name': name }">`

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle with jQuery and knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/nnsBQ/4/ (now shows OP's problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout does not set the `this` to the current element inside the `event` binding handlers.

So you need to use the [second argument of the handler function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters) which is the `event` object and get the data from there:

```
self.mouseEnter = function (viewModel, event) {
    var poszukiwane = $(event.currentTarget).data("name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
    console.log("mouseEnter");
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qWpK/).

But you are using Knockout so this is an anti-pattern to use the `data-` attributes to pass around your data because you anyway have all the data in your viewmodels so you can just write:

```
self.mouseEnter = function (viewModel, event) {
    var poszukiwane = viewModel.name; //viewModel is the currently hovered point
    console.log(poszukiwane);
    console.log("mouseEnter");
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tXEZ/).